# Finding employees' overall average times for multiple entries

Tags: mysql

With MySql, I am trying to write a query to find the average frequency in which employees update their cases. The table name is `tgs_doc_his` and there are three columns I need to use: EmpID, CaseID and ActualDate. An employee checks out the case, which the system makes the first date entry. Then there are several different history updates the employee can to until the case is closed. These statuses are irrelevant but I include thsi information to make it easier to see what I am trying to do.
It might look like:

```
EmpID | CaseID | ActualDate      | Status
1     , 1      , 2014-01-01 15:00, Checked Out
1     , 2      , 2014-01-02 08:00, Checked Out
1     , 1      , 2014-01-02 09:00, Attempted
1     , 2      , 2014-01-02 10:30, Delivered
2     , 3      , 2014-01-02 11:00, Checked Out
1     , 1      , 2014-01-02 12:00, Delivered
2     , 3      , 2014-01-02 14:45, Delivered
```

Here you can see I have two(2) employees and three(3) cases. How would I figure out the average amount of time an employee has between status updates overall for every case?

Example. Employee 1's case1 averages 7.0 hours + Case2 Ave = 2.5 hours for a total average of 4.75 hours for all of his cases while employee 2's overall average is 3.75 hours.

I want this returned:

```
ID, AveTime
1, 4.75
2, 3.75
```

Is this too much of a challenge? I've been pulling out my hair here.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please include your attempted solution(s) in the question, and explain how the results differ from the desired results.

Comment: My primary key for the employee is EmpID and the primary key for the case is CaseID.

Comment: How do you get average 7 hours for employee 1 case 1? 18 hours between checkout and attempted, then 3 hours between attempted and delivered, average is 10.5.

Comment: Sorry - I was looking at the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT delivered.empID, AVG(delivered.ActualDate - checkout.ActualDate) AS AveTime
FROM tgs_doc_his AS delivered 
JOIN tgs_doc_his AS checkout ON delivered.empID = checkout.empID
WHERE delivered.Status = 'Delivered'
AND check.Status = 'Checked Out'
GROUP BY delivered.empID
```

UPDATE:

```
select empid, avg(datediff)/3600 AS avetime
from (
    select empid, 
           if(@curemp = empid and @curcase = caseid, unix_timestamp(actualdate)-@prevdate, null) as datediff,
           @prevdate := unix_timestamp(actualdate),
           @curemp := empid, @curcase := caseid
    from tgs_doc_his
    cross join (select @curemp := null, @curcase := null, @prevdate := null) vars
    order by empid, caseid, actualdate) times
group by empid
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b640/7)

Comment: Thanks, Barmar, but I don't really care about the status. I am just trying to get the an employee's average times between each update for every case he has.

Comment: I've updated with a query that just calculates the time difference between successive actions on the same case, and averages them.

Comment: It seems so close - I ran the query and it resulted in:
user_id, avetime
3, NULL
38, NULL
41, 18.887777777777778
42, NULL

Comment: Results:
EmpID AveTime
3 null
38 null
41 18.88777778
42 null

Original values:
CaseID EmpID ActualDate
5021447 38 2014-02-06 00:18:15
5021448 3 2014-02-06 01:02:24
6021449 3 2014-02-06 13:43:08
6021450 42 2014-02-06 14:20:46
6021451 42 2014-02-06 14:21:15
6021449 41 2014-02-06 14:33:46
6021451 41 2014-02-06 14:36:02
6021452 42 2014-02-06 14:37:44
6021453 42 2014-02-06 14:38:26
6021454 42 2014-02-06 14:39:19
6021451 41 2014-02-06 14:44:48
6021452 41 2014-02-07 10:31:44
7021455 42 2014-02-07 10:38:04
7021455 41 2014-02-07 10:39:26
7021455 41 2014-02-07 10:40:11
7021456 3 2014-02-07 13:44:19

Comment: In case you hadn't noticed, there's no formatting in comments. I don't know what you expect me to do with that. I don't know why it doesn't work for you -- as you can see it works fine in my sqlfiddle.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with your sample data?

Comment: I attempted to use that, however, I'm a little lost. Instead, I set up www.lsatalk.com with PHPMyAdmin, User Name: testusr  Password: V8xmCb5YNmTVhGqP  and you can go in and do whatever to mess with the lest table I set up. I've been messing around with it on and off all day and can't seem to get anything to do what I want. lol. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Sorry - I did notice there was no formatting. When I posted it :)  I've never posted here before so i didn't know it would strip away the table formatting. Sorry!

Comment: Employee 41 is the only one who has more than one entry for any case, so he's the only one we can calculate an average for.

Comment: If you look at my actual table, I have many entries for different employee ID's. It's showing my null values on everything except 41 where it shows me 18.877...

Comment: All the other employees only have one row for each case. I only calculate elapsed time between rows for the same case. Did I misunderstand what you wanted?

Comment: If you don't care about time within cases, but just by employee, remove all references to `caseid` and `@curcase` from my query.

Comment: Barmar - I'm a complete idiot - it works! You are a genius! Do you do any freelance work? let me know.